# Is the Object stored in each position of the array in Arrays.fill(Object[], Object) the same object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am doing something where I have code like this

```
Object[] array = new Object[10];
Arrays.fill(array, new Object());
```

my question is, will `array[0] == array[1]` be true, or just `array[0].equals(array[1])`? Or in other words, are all of the values in the array the same exact object or equivalent objects?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure what Object Reference meant. Sorry.

Comment: No. Arrays hold references or primitives, not objects. Every element of the array is set to the same reference to an object.

Comment: Is that related to the whole pointer thing in C++/C?

Comment: @EliSadoff: Yes. Java "object references" are a bit like C/C++ "pointers" except you can't directly manipulate them/access their raw values. The reference tells the JVM where the object is in memory, but it isn't the object; it's just a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc for `Arrays.fill` states:

> Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the specified array of Objects.

Thus, since `==` compares references, `array[0]==array[1]` will return true. Arrays.fill would even work if equals was defined as simply `return false;`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for asking such a basic question.